# Kivy Not showing two buttons

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to develop a kaivy app, I am fairly new to this. I tried to make a simple screen with two buttons, but I am seeing only one button (button1, check in). I want to display two buttons side by side. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

button1 = '''
FloatLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'Check In'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 0
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
'''

button2 = '''
FloatLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'SOS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.5, 'center_y': 1.5}
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 45
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
'''

class RotationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(button1)
    def build2(self):
        return Builder.load_string(button2)

RotationApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your App is run, kivy runs the `build` method and uses the returned widget as the root widget. In your case, you return the button from your button1 string and that's it, job done.

The problem is that kivy doesn't know or care that you wrote a `build2` method, it doesn't call it and wouldn't know what to do with the returned widget even if it did.

There are lots of ways to create two adjacent buttons, and I'm not sure what your overall goal is, but a simple option is just to modify one of your kv language strings to contain two buttons in the same layout. I replaced the `FloatLayout` with a `BoxLayout` which automatically resizes them to be adjacent:

```
button1 = '''
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'Check In'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 0
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
    Button:
            text: 'SOS'
            size_hint: None, None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.5, 'center_y': 1.5}
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle: 45
                    origin: self.center
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix

'''
```

I haven't tried this code, and you might get some weird behaviour/overlap from your rotation, but it's the right general idea for placing adjacent widgets and having them both be displayed.

Comment: Your code is excellent !! Thanks !! I can see two buttons, but they are displaying at left side, while I need them at center or bottom. Do you know how to do that? Also, I searched kivy docs, but couldn't find a proper way to display a text on clicking one of this button. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To change their position, change the layout parameters. The right way to do it depends on the rest of your program, but your original idea of using pos_hint is one way to do it if you switch back to a FloatLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in a floating layout to add 3 buttons

```
<Button>:
    font_size:15
    color:1,0.1,0.1,1
    size_hint:0.1,0.1

<FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"left":1}
        text:"Subscribe"  

    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.5,"top":0.5}
        text:"Login"  

    Button:
        pos_hint: {"right":1}
        text:"Signup"
```